# Problem running tests under Netbeans

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans

I am running some Junit tests and Netbeans behaves strangely giving the report in "Output" window:

```
Testcase: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1):        FAILED
No tests found in uk.ac.cam.ch.wwmm.chemicaltagger.ChemistryPOSTaggerTest
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in uk.ac.cam.ch.wwmm.chemicaltagger.ChemistryPOSTaggerTest


Test uk.ac.cam.ch.wwmm.chemicaltagger.ChemistryPOSTaggerTest FAILED (crashed)
test:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

The (5) tests are there. I have run mvn test which runs them but fails on OutOfMemoryError. Is this likely to be the cause of the Netbeans problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you created your test file? Manually, or using NB wizard? (Tools - Create JUnit test from Java file's popup menu)

If you are using JUnit 3, all test methods in your test file must start with "test", e.g.

```
public void testFoo() { //some testing here :) }
```

With JUnit 4, a '@Test' annotation is required, e.g.

```
@Test
public void myOwnTestFoo() { //...}
```

Otherwise JUnit does not recognize the test and throws AssertionFailedError error.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to make this Junit4 compliant (@Test, no junit.framework etc. but I suspect NB is still trying to use Junit3)

Comment: You may add/remove JUnit libraries in the "Test Libraries" package of your NB project. Make sure, that there is only JUnit 4.x left.
I also reccomend to create some test using the NB wizard - it will create correct test file. At least for inspiration for your own one :)